# Установка пакетов через composer

Tags: php, yii2, composer

Устанавливаю пакет через `composer require dvizh/yii2-field "@dev"`

Выдает ошибку:

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for dvizh/yii2-field @dev -> satisfiable by dvizh/yii2-field[dev-master].
    - dvizh/yii2-field dev-master requires asofter/yii2-imperavi-redactor dev-master@dev -> satisfiable by asofter/yii2-imperavi-redactor[dev-master] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

Пробовал через composer update, та же ошибка. Кто знает, что за проблема? Это я пытаюсь модуль yii2-shop установить

Comment: Так ошибка же и говорит, что надо выбрать не dev.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте указать в composer.json **"minimum-stability": "dev"**, чтобы композер грузил "нестабильные" версии. По умолчанию композер работает в **stable** режиме и загружает только стабильные версии.